# Using Matlab Fmincon as a substitute for Excel solver tool

Tags: matlab, solver

I'm an amateur Matlab user. I turned to Matlab as the solver in excel restricts how many variables can be used variables. I'm trying to maximise a function subject to constraints using Fmincon. However I'm getting an error when I try to run it.

My code is:

```
% Objective function m file:

function f = objectivefunction3(x)

f = -FinalAlphas*x'+ x*VCV*x'

% Code to run Fmincon:

[x, fval] = fmincon(@objectivefunction2,x0,A,B)
```

I get the following error when running it:

```
Error in objectivefunction3 (line 2)

f = FinalAlphas*x'- x*VCV*x'
```

Error in fmincon (line 631)

Comment: Firstly I"m assuming it's a typo in your Fmincon where you call objectivefunctrion2 instead of 3? Secondly what is FinalAlphas and what is VCV? And also what is the error that you get?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that you created function `objectivefunction3` with only one input parameter, i.e. `x` and one output variable `f`.

First I suggest trying to run your function on its own to check if it is working like you want. So for this I think you should either declare the variables you state in your function (i.e. `FinalAlphas` and `VCV`) or make them input parameters. 
Option 1 (declare function variables):

```
function f = objectivefunction3(x)

FinalAlphas = ... % put your values here
VCV = ... % put your values here
f = -FinalAlphas*x'+ x*VCV*x'
```

Option 2 (define as input parameters):

```
function f = objectivefunction3(x,FinalAlphas,VCV)

f = -FinalAlphas*x'+ x*VCV*x'
```

See if you get this to work on its own, then try to implement it into `fmincon`.